# Нужно переименовать метку [py-script] в [pyscript]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, переименование-метки

PyScript везде упоминается только в слитном написании, примеры:

- Официальный сайт: [Say Hello to PyScript](https://pyscript.net/#:%7E:text=Say%20Hello%20to%20PyScript)
- Гитхаб: https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript
- python.land: [PyScript: Run Python In Your Browser, Including Numpy And Pandas](https://python.land/pyscript)
- Хабр: [Как работать с PyScript — фреймворком для фронтенда на Python](https://habr.com/ru/company/skillfactory/blog/669814/)

Но создавший метку участник почему-то решил написать как `py-script`.

По метке на данный момент всего два вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/py-script

Можно было бы переметить вручную, но редактор меток в вопросе ругается, что новая метка pyscript слишком похожа на py-script и предлагает обсудить на Мете (что я и делаю).

**UPD:** Как вариант - можно добавить метку pyscript, py-script сделать синонимом.

Comment: Переименованы с синонимом.

Comment: @Nofate [meta-tag:статус-завершено] довесишь?